# Calculate aspect ratio from 2D shape in 3D space

Tags: transformations, geometry, projections, perspective, space

Given the 4 coordinates of a 2D shape in a 3D space I want to calculate its aspect ratio.

The 3D space is created with 2 vanishing points.

The 4 coordinates - marked blue - are the 2D coordinates on the display.
in the example they should be roughly (14, 5.5), (19, 5), (20.3, 7.3), (25.3, 6).

I'm not sure if this is possible at all, if someone could find proof that for 2 different aspect ratios the 2D coordinates are the same this problem would be unsolvable.

My exapmle:

[image]

Comment: Can we assume that the corners are 90 degree angles

Comment: The table's corners are, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ratio is with a quick and dirty visual measurement $665:501$ which is approximately $5:4$. You can measure it by taking the ratio of the vanishing angles $\alpha/\beta$ (*see picture 1*) because we are so close to the center.

[image: Angles]

**Image 1**: Ratio of the inbound angles

We can check the situation visually by drawing a 2 point perspective grid. For this we need the center line between the vanishing points.

[image: Perspective grid]

**Image 2**: Seems about right.

Comment: How would one calculate the aspect ratio if we weren't so close to the center?

Comment: @succubus there is a lengthy explanation [here](http://www.handprint.com/HP/WCL/perspect3.html) but you can do this with matrix calculation. Just didnt have time to outline the math.

Comment: @succcubbus please refer to [official help page](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) about merging your account to regain the ownership of the question.